# How to append node and attribute to an existing Xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I have the following XML file. I have to add a node using `XElement` and `XAttribute`. How to do this?

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner"> 
       <DataSets>
          <DataSet Name="Data">
              <Query>
                  <DataSourceName>DS1</DataSourceName>
                  <CommandText>SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Person</CommandText>
              </Query>
</DataSet>
    <DataSet Name="table22">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>DS1</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>New text2</CommandText>
      </Query>
```

How to add following XML text to above xml file at the end of both "/query" element using `XElement` And `XAttribute`

```
 <Fields>
        <Field Name="ReportId">
          <DataField>ReportId</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int64</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to select `<Query>` element first, then use [`AddAfterSelf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.addafterself%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to add `<Fields>` element after `<Query>` element, for example :

```
var doc = XElement.Parse(xml);
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition";
var query = doc.Element(ns + "DataSets").Element(ns + "DataSet").Element(ns + "Query");

Console.WriteLine("before :");
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("");

XNamespace rd = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner";
var field = new XElement(ns+"Fields",
                         new XElement(ns+"Field", new XAttribute("Name", "ReportId")
                                      , new XElement(ns+"DataField", "ReportId")
                                      , new XElement(rd + "TypeName", "System.Int64")));
query.AddAfterSelf(field);

Console.WriteLine("after :");
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

Comment: i want to add <rd:TypeName>System.Int64</rd:TypeName>, bt i am getting    <TypeName xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com//SQLServer//reporting//reportdesigner">System.Int64</TypeName> how to do it???

Comment: i have updated my question ....how to insert data if i have same node in my xml file

Comment: @ha07 how to add xml text after </Query> of DataSet name="table22"

Comment: Answered that in your other question. Changing/adding requirement on the go is rather annoying to me. If you posted another question for the change/new requirement, better inform the link and close/continue discussion in the previous post according to the original requirement

Comment: Sorrry m new to stack overflow..i dont know hw to close discussion an inform otherspls be easy on my side

Comment: To inform other, simply copy-paste link to your new question in comment. To close discussion, mark an answer accepted if it works to solve the original requirement, or delete the question.

Comment: well bt the answer you have posted,m getting error in that what should i do??