# How to add Xml text if xml file having same node

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xml-namespaces

I have Following xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
    <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="Data">
    <Query>
    <DataSourceName>DS1</DataSourceName>
    <CommandText>text</CommandText>
    </Query>
    </DataSet>
    <DataSet Name="table22">
    <Query>
    <DataSourceName>DS1</DataSourceName>
    <CommandText>New text2</CommandText>
    </Query>
    <Fields>
     </Fields>
```

I have to add following xml text between Fields open and close node,bt i dont know how to it.m new to xml can anyone please help me.Thanks!!!

```
Xml file to add is:

    <Field Name="ReportId">
      <DataField>ReportId</DataField>
      <TypeName xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com//SQLServer//reporting//reportdesigner">System.Int64</TypeName>
    </Field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very similar to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341173/how-to-append-node-and-attribute-to-an-existing-xml-file/). You can use the same approach except a slight change in the part where we select `<Query>` element to be like this :

```
var query = doc.Elements(ns + "DataSets")
               .Elements(ns + "DataSet")
               .FirstOrDefault(o => o.Attribute("Name") != null &&
                                    o.Attribute("Name").Value == "table22")
               .Element(ns + "Query");
```

Comment: Sorry slightly mistake from side in question ,i have updated it.i tried your suggestion bt gives error @var query that nullReferenceException was unhanled

Comment: for debugging purpose, try to trim the query to `.FirstOrDefault(...);` part only, does it give the same exception?

Comment: Updated my answer. I suspect some `<DataSet>` element doesn't have Name attribute, hence caused exception in the previous attempt

Comment: yup...Sir it works fine.thanks for your help.i was struct to solve this problem from last 2 days..thanks again :)

Comment: Great, don't forget to accept the answer to confirm your problem already solved.

Comment: ,one last change in my xml file to add new text..plz have look of my update question

Comment: I already warned you about changing/adding requirement. Open new question and include your attempt to solve the problem (even if it didn't work), people around SO always appreciate that.

Comment: ok i thought if i upload new question then it will be not correct,because i have already uploade here same question before ,bt now as i want some minor change i just edit this question....well by the i have now solved this question so now can i upload my solution here..

Comment: If you already accepted previous question, the next question is rarely get closed as duplicate (as long as both has different requirement).